# How to plot a phase portrait of a map for many initial points?

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, iterators

Suppose I have a 2-dimensional map $x_{n+1} = f(x_{n},y_{n}), \quad y_{n+1} = g(x_{n},y_{n})$, and a number of initial points $(x_{0}, y_{0})$ in some given range. I take each initial point and iterate the map a certain number of times. How do I generate a list of all the results and a phase portrait that shows all the iterates of all the initial condition?

For example, take $x_{n+1} = x_{n} + 2y_{n}, \quad y_{n+1} = y_{n}$ with $x_{0} \in [1,3]$ and $y_{0} \in [2,5]$, with these intervals partitioned with a step size of $0.2$ and, therefore, I have $150$ initial points.

I assume I should use `RecurrenceTable` and `ListPlot`, but beyond that I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1):

[`NestList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html) is built for this kind of thing. Define `f` and `g`:

```
f[x_, y_] := x + 2 y
g[x_, y_] := y
```

Then you can generate all your initial points with

```
Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 3, 0.2}, {j, 2, 5, 0.2}], 1]

(* {{-0.5, -0.5}, {-0.5, -0.4}, {-0.5, -0.3}, ...,
    {0.5, 0.3}, {0.5, 0.4}, {0.5, 0.5}} *)
```

`NestList` can get you the iterates for an initical point, and you can [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) (`/ @`) that over the list of inital points to get all the iterates:

```
points = NestList[{f[#[[1]], #[[2]]], g[#[[1]], #[[2]]]} &, #, 100] & /@ 
   Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 3, 0.2}, {j, 2, 5, 0.2}], 1];

ListPlot[points]
```

[image]

Notice that the iterated from each initial point are coloured differently by `ListPlot`.

Using the [Duffing map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duffing_map) for another example:

```
f[x_, y_] := y
g[x_, y_] := -0.2 x + 2.75 y - y^3
points = NestList[{f[#[[1]], #[[2]]], g[#[[1]], #[[2]]]} &, #, 1000] & /@ 
   Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, -0.5, 0.5, 0.1}, {j, -0.5, 0.5, 0.1}], 1];
ListPlot[Flatten[points, 1]]
```

[image]

If you want to get rid of transients -- which is often the case -- you can simply `Drop` the first `n` points to obtain a cleaner plot:

```
points = Drop[
     NestList[{f[#[[1]], #[[2]]], g[#[[1]], #[[2]]]} &, #, 1000], 
     100] & /@ 
   Flatten[Table[{i, j}, {i, -0.5, 0.5, 0.1}, {j, -0.5, 0.5, 0.1}], 1];
ListPlot[Flatten[points, 1]]
```

[image]